# WPF Notify chain implementation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, notify

Here's the model:

```
public class Customer
{
    string Name;
    public ObservableCollection<Order> orders;
}

public class Order 
{ 
    int Id;
    public ObservableCollection<RequestStorage> Requests;
}

public class RequestStorage
{
    string Text;
    public ObservableCollection<Response> Responses;
}

public class Response
{
    string Text;
}
```

**CustomersView.xaml** bound to **CustomersViewModel**, that has a property `ObservableCollection<*Customer*> Customers;`

**CustomersViewModel**

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class CustomersViewModel
{
    public CustomersViewModel()
    {
        //Load customers from database to Customers
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomersView.xaml**
Window's `DataContext` set to `CustomersViewModel`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}">
    ...
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    ...
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}">
                        ...
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Path=Id}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <ItemsControl Binding="{Path=Requests}" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Requests}" Binding="{Path=Responses}" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

**Q:** How do I notify **CustomersViewModel** when Responses collection has changed (e.g. a new Response added) so that **CustomersView.xaml** will update its UI for the specified Customer?

Comment: Can you post the CustomersViewModel? A little more info makes it easier to help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the design of the views is good you don't need to notify the `CustomerView`, because you would have something (e.g. `ResponsesList`) that is visualizing the responses collection. In that case you would have an item `DataTemplate` which would refresh automatically.

Comment: 1. I have a `CustomersView.xaml` with `DataContext=CustomersViewModel`. 2. `CustomersView.xaml` has a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource=Customers`.   3. `DataGrid` column "Customer name" is bound like `Binding={Binding Path=Name}`   4. `DataGrid.RowDetails` has a `DataGrid` that bound to `Requests` and `Responses`.   5. When application starts everything works fine, all data is shown as it must be. 6. When I programmaticaly add a new `Response` the data in `DataGrid` doesn't update. I need the UI to be updated onfly when data  changed.

Comment: Well please show us the `CustomersView.xaml`, if possible only the important parts (the bindings). I'm sure, it can be solved without implementing this notification chain. Believe me, you really don't want to implement it. ;o)

Comment: Responses list sholud be a observableCollecton too.
ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged so when you add/remove an item, UI will get updated

Comment: @JohnSmith From what I'm seeing you should get a `BindingExpression` error, since `Responses` is not a collection in `Order` class, at least I'm assuming that because it's not in the model classes. Otherwise you must post the VMs you're using, so that we can get an idea how you probably transformed the models to the VMs.

Comment: @DHN I'm sorry, I forgot to point `DataContext`. Reponses bound like `<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Requests}" ItemsSource="{Binding Responses}" />`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented by now is a class `CustomerRegister` that contains `List<Customer>` and providing methods for getting/adding/editing/saving a.s.o `Customer` objects. `CustomersViewModel` cantains `CustomersRegister`.
Furthermore, `CustomerRegister` notifies `CustomersViewModel` when any changes made by rising event handlers.
And finally, every `object` from "Model" notifies `CustomerRegister` when its properties changed.
It seems to be quite complicated, so I will appreciate any other option.

Comment: Can you post the code please? I'm just interested, how you solved since I developed an approach by myself. :o)

Comment: @DHN, Im using standart EventHandlers and Update() method in CustomersRegister to update ViewModel. Im not sure you're gonna use it. It works correct but it takes almost 10 seconds to update the CustomersView UI. I will keep seeking...

Comment: I posted you my class. Not sure if it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the class I would use to listen to the changes of the child collections. Maybe you can use it.

```cs
public abstract class ChildListenerBase
{
    public void RegisterChildCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // register to collection changed event
        collection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChangedInternal;

        // register to items
        foreach (T item in collection)
            item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    public void UnregisterChildCollection<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // unregister to collection changed event
        collection.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChangedInternal;

        // unregister to item
        foreach (T item in collection)
            item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChangedInternal(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // probably you have to add some more cases
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                    ((INotifyPropertyChanged) item).PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                    ((INotifyPropertyChanged) item).PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(sender, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // override method in derived class to handle some additional stuff
    }

    // implement the reaction on item changes here
    protected abstract void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
}
```